# Creating a method in the controller, which takes and id

Tags: c#, angular

I made a method in my service, which sort a list by removing items which have a specific id, and show a list of items.

```
 public List<IngredientBO> GetAllFilteredIngredient(List<int> ids)
    {


        var Ingredient = GetAllIndgredients();
        var filteredIngredient = Ingredient.Where(i => !ids.Contains(i.Id)).ToList();
        return filteredIngredient;

    }



    public List<IngredientBO> GetAllIndgredients()
    {
        using (var uow = facade.UnitOfWork)
        {
            return uow.IngredientRepository.GetAll().Select(i => Iconv.Convert(i)).ToList();

        }
    }
```

The method should work.
My problem is when creating the method in the controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public IngredientBO GetFilteredList([FromBody] List<int> ids)
    {
        return facade.ProductService.GetAllFilteredIngredient(ids);

    }
```

I get the error "Use expression body for methods".
Can someone help me with making the controller

Comment: You seem to be trying to return a `List<IngredientBO>` but your signature promises a `IngredientBO`. That doesn't solve your problem, but it will be a next one...

Comment: Actually, is `Use expression body for methods` an error, or a hint/warning? It seems Visual studio is telling you that you can rewrite your method as `public IngredientBO GetFilteredList([FromBody] List<int> ids) => facade.ProductService.GetAllFilteredIngredient(ids);` - you still need to fix the return type though!

Comment: Yeah that seemed to be the problem here.
The method should also return a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your return type is wrong. Should be `List<IngredientBO>`

```
[HttpPost]
public List<IngredientBO> GetFilteredList([FromBody] List<int> ids)
{
    return facade.ProductService.GetAllFilteredIngredient(ids);

}
```